# After deployment, Vue Nuxt SPA is not correctly displayed even though yarn start does work

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

### summery

I"ve tried to deploy sample Vue Nuxt SPA to AWS S3.
My Sample SPA is correctly displayed in my local Ubuntu20.04 environment with `yarn start`.
However SPA on S3 does not work correctly and shows error.

I want to know how to deloy correctly and show the same content as I did in my local environment.

### what I've tried

1. Run `yarn start`
2. Confirm SPA does work in my local environment.
   [image]
3. Run `yarn generate`.
4. Deploy `/dist` to S3.
5. Configure S3 access rigihts.
6. Confirm SPA does not work correctly in S3.
   [image]

### show some codes

here is the github repo I've tried.
https://github.com/jpskgc/vue-nuxt-spa-sample/tree/main

Comment: Just to be sure that nothing wrong with your project. Can you `yarn generate` it and drag&drop it on app.netlify.com/drop?

Comment: Yes. `yarn generate` first, then upload `/dist` to S3.

Comment: Can you try it on the link that I just gave above?

Comment: https://vibrant-ride-9e4fd9.netlify.app/ But still it fails in  case of S3.

Comment: Alright yeah, so it's an S3 issue for sure. How did you proceeded for this one?